# Columns in fstream data reading zero! (Array of Payroll Objects) C++

Tags: c++, arrays, object, fstream, zero

I have been google searching like crazy and trying my best, but having some trouble. Basically for homework, we gotta make an array of payroll objects, using the general format I've made below...

I'm having trouble. The .dat file we are given to test looks like this:

```
40.0     10.00
38.5      9.50
16.0      7.50
42.5      8.25
22.5      9.50
40.0      8.00
38.0      8.00
40.0      9.00
44.0     11.75
```

When I execute the program, it shows the first column of objects, but will always replace the 2nd column values with a 0. 
Any ideas?

(TL;DR.... Currently it reads "Employee #1: 40, 0" rather than "Employee #1: 40, 10.00"... etc)

Here's my code.... (not 100% done yet just testing datafile atm)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Payroll
{
    private:
        double payRate;     // holds an employee hourly pay rate
        double hoursWorked;  // an employee's hours worked

    public:
        Payroll()  // empty constructor sets the payRate and hoursWorked to zero
        {   payRate = 0;
            hoursWorked = 0;
        }
        Payroll(double payR, double hoursW) //constructor checks for payR and hoursW to be positive& sets to values
        {   if (payR < 0)
                payRate = 0;
            else 
                payRate = payR;

            if (hoursW < 0)
                hoursW = 0;
            else
                hoursW = hoursWorked;
        }
        void setPayRate(double payR) //mutator for payRate; checks for payR to be positive or sets to zero
        {   if (payR < 0)
                payRate = 0;
            else payRate = payR;
        }
        void setHoursWorked(double hoursW) //mutator for hoursWorked; checks for positive hoursW or sets to zero
        {
            if (hoursW < 0)
                hoursW = 0;
            else
                hoursW = hoursWorked;
        }
        double getPayRate() //accessor to return payRate
        {   return payRate; }

        double getHoursWorked() // accessor to return hoursWorked
        {   return hoursWorked; }

        double getGrossPay() // computes and returns gross pay including OVERTIME, if any
        {   if (hoursWorked > 8)
                return ((payRate * 1.5) * hoursWorked);
            else 
                return (payRate * hoursWorked);
        }
};

int main()
{
    const int EMPLOYEES = 7;
    double payRate, hoursWorked;

    ifstream datafile;
    datafile.open("payroll.dat");

    Payroll payArray[EMPLOYEES];

    if (!datafile)
        cout << "AHH!! Error opening this file!! SRY!!!" << endl;
    else
    {   for (int index = 0; index < EMPLOYEES; index++)
        {   
            datafile >> payRate >> hoursWorked; 
            payArray[index].setPayRate(payRate);
            payArray[index].setHoursWorked(hoursWorked);
            cout << "Employee #" << index + 1 << ": ";
            cout <<  payArray[index].getPayRate() << ", " << payArray[index].getHoursWorked() << endl;

        }   
    }

}
```

Currently will output

```
Employee #1: 40, 0
Employee #2: 38.5, 0
Employee #3: 16.0, 0
...
Employee #7: 38, 0
```

I want it to read the other column without giving me zero :( 
Thank you, I am going to bed for now.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment statements in `setHoursWorked` are wrong; they should be assigning *to* the instance variable `hoursWorked`, not the parameter `hoursW`.

Comment: OMG I can't believe I overlooked that... Currently slapping myself right now... Thank you for the help.